# Ho to call this person serving wedding registrations?

Tags: word-request

In some countries, they have secular weeding registration ceremonies, in which the groom and the bride are supposed to put their signatures on some official paper and exchange their wedding rings. The ceremony is not religious; however, it is just as solemn. Parents of both newly-weds, of course, are present.

Usually, there is a person, it is typically a lady, who would firstly say some speech about marriage and about the newly-weds' parents. That lady is the representative of the state and she has that very paper that the newly-weds have to sign, after which the marriage is considered to be officially registered.

So, on one hand, that lady is representing the state, but on the other hand, her big function in this ceremony is to give a speech that would reflect on newly-weds' and parents' lives and refresh the listeners' understanding of the importance of marriage.

My question is: how would this lady (her office) be called in English?

Comment: I am unaware of any Western-based ceremony that has such a "hybrid" function. Normally, there is either a fully religious ceremony of some type or there is a purely secular (administrative) procedure with signatures but no speeches made by anyone.

Comment: @JasonBassford - That's what, in fact, made me extremely hard to find an English word for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lady is probably someone from the registrar's office. A *[registrar](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/registrar)* is someone who is in charge of official records of births, marriages, and deaths (Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is celebrant, which the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English defines as '[someone who performs or takes part in a religious ceremony](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/celebrant)', but in Australia, this is the official term for anyone who is authorised by the government to perform marriages (whether they are religious, or an employee of the Registry of Births, Deaths and Marriages, or a private person who has completed a government-approved course and been licenced as a celebrant).

An employee of the Registry *might* be referred to informally as 'a registrar', but the official term is 'marriage celebrant'.